# Angular subscribe() returning undefined

Tags: angular, http, service, subscribe

How to I solve problem with subcribe() to my app.component if my console shows me the following thing: **ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
at AppComponent.push../src/app/app.component.ts.AppComponent.ngOnInit**

**data.service:**

```
   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
   import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
   import { Observable, Subject, ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';
   import { from, of, range } from 'rxjs/create';
   import { map, filter, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';


 @Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
    })


export class DataService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  fetchData(){
    this.http.get('assets/ninjas.json').pipe(
     map((res) => return res.json()))}}
```

**app.components:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  ninjas = [];

  constructor(private newService: DataService){ }

  ngOnInit(){
   this.newService.fetchData().subscribe(
    (data) => this.ninjas = data;
   );
  }
 }
```

Comment: `fetchData` should return the Observable: `return this.http.get(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return the observable in your service,

```
 fetchData(){
    return this.http.get('assets/ninjas.json').pipe(
     map((res) => return res.json()))}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the 'pipe', you don't need it:

```
fetchData(){
    return this.http.get('assets/ninjas.json');
}
```

Comment: This would be true if OP was using the new `HttpClient`, but it looks like they're still using the (now deprecated) `Http` service